# addEventListener to no action?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, addeventlistener

I would like a modal to pop up if there has been no action on the page by the user for the last 3 seconds. Is there a way for addEventListener to run a function upon no action for 3 seconds?

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` to schedule an action in 3 seconds. Add an event listener that cancels the timer if the user performs some action.

Comment: What action do you mean? A mouse move or something like that?

Comment: Specifically, a keyboard press. I want a modal to disappear upon a keyboard press, but I want it to reappear if the user has not pressed a key in the last 3 seconds.

Comment: add a listener for a keypress and use it to reset the timeout. if the timeout fires it opens the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` to open the modal after 3 seconds and use an event listener for key presses (or key up, etc) to reset the timeout.

```
let timeout = undefined;

function resetTimer() {
  if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }

  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    // open modal, call resetTimer() when it is closed to restart the check...
    /*
       modal.onClose = resetTimer;
       modal.open();
    */
    console.log('open modal');
  }, 3000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  // every time a key is pressed reset the timer
  document.addEventListener('keypress', resetTimer);
  // start the timer
  resetTimer();
};
```

Comment: @A-312 that's not correct - `clearInterval()` is used with `setInterval()`. In this case you only want to fire the event once after 3000 milliseconds, so it's better to use `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` to manage it - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp